# How to call this instance method

Tags: java, methods

Hi I am trying to call a non-static method with a return type of boolean,

if there was a static in there I would know how to do it, but the static seems to throw it all away, I have tried to create a new instance of the method with the line

```
    Loginn auth = new Loginn(1,2,3)
```

and also

```
   Login.Loginn auth = new Login.Loginn(1,2,3)
```

The code can be found here...

http://www.pastebin.com/qwAtR7u0/

thanks

c

Comment: I'm really confused on your question now.  You might want to look up a basic java tutorial going over static / non-static methods.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html  Also an example of the errors you are seeing would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To call a static method you code `result = ClassName.methodName(parameters);`

(But I can't, at first glance, see any static methods in the code you referenced.)

Loginn you'd call as:

```
Login instance = new Login();
boolean result = instance.Loginn(parameters);
```

Or you could do:

```
boolean result = new Login().Loginn(parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You call static methods like so:

```
Login.Loginn(1,2,3)
```

You don't need the new keyword.

Also, you probably don't want to assign anything to Login.Loginn whatever that may be...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a static method in that code you posted.

```
public class Login {
    ...

    public boolean Loginn(String UserName, String PassWord, String IP) throws UnknownHostException, IOException { ... }
}
```

To invoke that method, you simply call the method name on the object instance:

```
Login myLogin = new Login();
myLogin.Loginn( username, password, IP);
```

Comment: My bad, i assumed as I didnt use the word static it is not static... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

if its a static method with return type of Boolean then try :

```
if(Login.Loginn(1,2,3))
{
//your code here
}
else
{
//some code
}
```

Or

```
boolean result = Login.Loginn(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what's there, you seem to want:

```
Login login = new Login();
login.Loginn(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling a method at all!
You're calling a constructor.

It's called like this:

```
Loginn auth = new Loginn("username", "password", "IP");
```

You can't call it with integers - the 3 parameters are `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `Loginn` is a public method, not static. So you need to call like:

```
Login login = new Login();
login.Loginn("user","pass","ip");
```

If you transform the method to static (`public static Loginn`) then you can use:

```
Login.Loginn
```

Also, take a look at the [java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) for better naming your methods.